# JPopupMenu layout modification

Tags: java, jpopupmenu

How can I set color to white for these parts of JPopUpMenu?
(see image below)

[image: JPopupMenu Image]

I try to set all `UIManager.*.Background` option but nothing happened.

i build a gui in matlab. to achieve my goal I use java component. I try

`UIManager.put('MenuItem.background',Color.WHITE);` `UIManager.put('MenuBar.background',Color.WHITE);` `UIManager.put('PopupMenu.background',Color.WHITE);` `UIManager.put('Menu.background',Color.WHITE);`

before building the gui. The result is showed in previous picture.. I am new in java, I don't know if I can achieve the same result modifying other option/s

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Add it to the question by editing it.. Do not add it as a comment.